# pandas read_csv with final column containing commas

Tags: python, json, csv, pandas

So I have a csv dataset that by my book is well formed, and I'm trying to get the `pandas` package to load it correctly.  The header consists of 5 column names , but the final column consists of JSON objects which contain unescaped commas.  e.g.

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,{K1:V1,K2:V2}
```

I'm loading my data with a simple `training = pd.read_csv('data/training.dat')`

however, pandas is clearly misinterpreting the additional commas as new unlabeled columns, and I'm getting an error like this:

```
CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 75 fields in line 3, saw 84
```

I'm trying to navigate the docs, but clearly failing,  does anyone know how to correctly configure the `pd.read_csv` command to parse it correctly?

I guess the alternative is I could hack together a script that flattens the JSON objects using a union of their keys as columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it feasible for you to replace `{` with `"{`, and `}` with `}"`, it can be read correctly by: `pd.read_csv('data/training.dat',quotechar='"',skipinitialspace=True)`

## Edit:

Or go for a regular expression based solution:

```
In [205]:
print pd.read_csv('a.data',sep=",(?![^{]*\})", header=None)
   0  1  2  3              4
0  A  B  C  D              E
1  1  2  3  4  {K1:V1,K2:V2}

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: I really like that regex-based solution.  I didn't realize sep could parse regex.

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what you're trying to do with the JSON. If you just want to ignore it, probably the easiest way is to set the comment char to `{` (For this and the next, I've assumed you don't have any braces in your other columns.)

```
pd.read_csv(
    'woo.csv',
    comment='{' 
)
```

It is possible to extract elements from the JSON using a custom separator with `read_csv`, though I'm not at all convinced this is a sensible approach. Pandas will turn the separator into a column if it's a capturing group (it uses `re.split` internally), so I can get a column containing the JSON. Unfortunately I get a load of empty columns too because of that; hence the `dropna`.

I sent the JSON through `loads` and `dumps`, though obviously you'd want to do something more sensible. :)

```
json_bit = lambda x: json.dumps(json.loads(x))

pd.read_csv(
    'woo.csv', 
    sep=r'(\{.*\})$|,', 
    converters={'None.3': json_bit}
).dropna(axis=1)
```

Sample CSV

```
A,B,C,D,E
1,2,3,4,{"K1":"V1","K2":"V2"}
3,2,3,4,{"K1": "V1", "k£": {"k3": "v3"},  "K2":"V2"}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to preprocess csv file, just use engine type python :

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('sample.csv', sep=',', engine='python')
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem.  I don't see how specifying the engine type will make a column entry get interpreted as a `dict`.