# double quoted elements in csv cant read with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have an input file where every value is stored as a string.
It is inside a csv file with each entry inside double quotes.

Example file:

```
"column1","column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6"
"AM", "07", "1", "SD", "SD", "CR"
"AM", "08", "1,2,3", "PR,SD,SD", "PR,SD,SD", "PR,SD,SD"
"AM", "01", "2", "SD", "SD", "SD"
```

There are only six columns. What options do I need to enter to pandas read_csv to read this correctly?

I currently am trying:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(file, quotechar='"')
```

but this gives me the error message:
`CParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 6 fields in line 3, saw 14`

Which obviously means that it is ignoring the '"' and parsing every comma as a field.
However, for line 3, columns 3 through 6 should be strings with commas in them. ("1,2,3", "PR,SD,SD", "PR,SD,SD", "PR,SD,SD")

How do I get pandas.read_csv to parse this correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: If you are good with regex you can use it in the sep arguement to read_csv...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091356/pandas-read-csv-with-final-column-containing-commas

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This will work. It falls back to the python parser (as you have non-regular separators, e.g. they are comma and sometimes space). If you only have commas it would use the c-parser and be much faster.

```
In [1]: import csv

In [2]: !cat test.csv
"column1","column2", "column3", "column4", "column5", "column6"
"AM", "07", "1", "SD", "SD", "CR"
"AM", "08", "1,2,3", "PR,SD,SD", "PR,SD,SD", "PR,SD,SD"
"AM", "01", "2", "SD", "SD", "SD"

In [3]: pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep=',\s+',quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
pandas/io/parsers.py:637: ParserWarning: Falling back to the 'python' engine because the 'c' engine does not support regex separators; you can avoid this warning by specifying engine='python'.
  ParserWarning)
Out[3]: 
     "column1","column2" "column3"   "column4"   "column5"   "column6"
"AM"                "07"       "1"        "SD"        "SD"        "CR"
"AM"                "08"   "1,2,3"  "PR,SD,SD"  "PR,SD,SD"  "PR,SD,SD"
"AM"                "01"       "2"        "SD"        "SD"        "SD"
```

Comment: It does not work for me.. my huge csv that is time consuming to `sed` contains lines like `4366201,"Erud","Facebook,Ado-Ekiti","2018-03-22 10:38:42","UR",0,0,\N         ,\N,\N,\N,\N,\N` and gives `ParserError: '
' expected after '"'` I even tried `pd.read_csv("users.csv", sep=",", delimiter="\n", quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, engine="python", quotechar='"', encoding="utf-8")`

Comment: What finally worked for me was `pd.read_csv("users.csv", sep=",", encoding="utf-8", names=["id", "name"...])`

Comment: Note: sep=',\s*' seems to break using quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL.  It's seemed reading this is would be equivalent.  But, that's not what I found.  Leaving this here for others.

Comment: this only works for python engine. When you need low_memory=True the solution won't work

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me: (I used Python 3.9)

```
dataset = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=',', skipinitialspace=True)
```