# Pandas read_csv - How to handle a comma inside double quotes that are themselves inside double quotes

Tags: python, pandas

This is not the same question as [double quoted elements in csv cant read with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595819/double-quoted-elements-in-csv-cant-read-with-pandas).

The difference is that in that question: "ABC,DEF" was breaking the code.

Here, "ABC "DE" ,F" is breaking the code.

The whole string should be parsed in as 'ABC "DE", F'. Instead the inside double quotes are leading to the below-mentioned issue.

I am working with a csv file that contains the following type of entries:

> header1, header2, header3,header4
>
> 2001-01-01,123456,"abc def",V4
>
> 2001-01-02,789012,"ghi "jklm" n,op",V4

The second row of data is breaking the code, with the following error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 4 fields in line 1234, saw 5
```

I have tried playing with various `sep`, `delimiter` & `quoting` etc. arguments but nothing seems to work.

Can someone please help with this? Thank you!

Comment: Check this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595819/double-quoted-elements-in-csv-cant-read-with-pandas

Comment: It's not the same issue. Please see update to the question above. Thank you, Tom.

Comment: read the file as a single text string with fp.read. ` from io import StringIO; clean_text = text.replace(',"', '$$commadquote').replace('",', '$$dquotecomma').replace('"', "'").replace('$$commadquote', ',"').replace( '$$dquotecomma', '",');
pd.read_csv(StringIO(clean_text))

Answer (score 0):

Based on the two rows you have provided here is an option where the text file is read into a `Series` object and then regex extract is used via `Series.str.extract()` get the information you want in a `DataFrame`:

```
with open('so.txt') as f:
    contents = f.readlines()

s = pd.Series(contents)
```

`s` now looks like the following:

`0       header1, header2, header3,header4\n
1                                        \n
2          2001-01-01,123456,"abc def",V4\n
3                                        \n
4    2001-01-02,789012,"ghi "jklm" n,op",V4`

Now you can use regex extract to get what you want into a `DataFrame`:

```
df = s.str.extract('^([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}),([0-9]+),(.+),(\w{2})$')

# remove empty rows
df = df.dropna(how='all')
```

`df` looks like the following:

`0       1                  2   3
2  2001-01-01  123456          "abc def"  V4
4  2001-01-02  789012  "ghi "jklm" n,op"  V4`

and you can set your columns names with `df.columns = ['header1', 'header2', 'header3', 'header4']`