# Problems reading CSV in Pandas with commas and apostrophes inside double quotes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm really struggling with reading some messy string data from a CSV file into a DataFrame.
I'm working with Python 3.8.5 and Pandas 1.1.3

My CSV file contains integers, dates, and strings bookended with double quote " characters. An example of the first few rows is:

Using pd as an instance of Pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv


myfilename = 'Input.csv'
myexpenses = pd.read_csv(myfilename, skipinitialspace=True, quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
```

Consistently gives me:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 37 fields in line 3, saw 42
```

This is clearly because there are actually 41 commas spread across the 37 fields.  I'm not sure why these aren't being handled by the quotechar statement.

How can I handle these strings as a single field entry?

I've probably tried a dozen different tweaks of this function such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32743479/pandas-read-csv-with-extra-commas-in-column), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26595819/double-quoted-elements-in-csv-cant-read-with-pandas), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53708995/pandas-read-csv-how-to-handle-a-comma-inside-double-quotes-that-are-themselves), etc.

These include tweaking variables like `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL` without result.

Do I need to involve reg expressions?

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thank you in advance.

EDIT:  Added full code. For those asking, these are the columns and first five entry lines of the CSV file:

> Date,Employee,Project,Expense,Description,Units,Cost Rate,Cost Amount,Markup %,Charge Amount,Billable,Billed Status,Submit Status,Approved By,Reimbursable,Paid,Paid Date,Income Account,Expense Account,Class,Country,Purchase Tax Rate,Extra,Tax1 %,Tax2 %,Tax3 %,Credit Card,Check Number,Vendor Bill Number,Invoice Number,Client,Attachments,Memo,Created By,Created On,Last Updated By,Last Updated

> 8/27/2021,"Lastname, Firstname","2021-123 - Bob & Bob (Bob's - New York, NY) Project - Support",Meals:Project Meals,Meals,1,43.64,43.64,0,43.64,True,Un Billed,Un-Submitted,,False,False,8/27/2021,,,Meals-Project,U.S. Dollar,0,False,0,0,0,1234-56 - Lastname - 1234,,,,"Bob & Bob, Inc.",1,,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021

> 8/27/2021,"Lastname, Firstname","2021-123 - Bob & Bob (Bob's - New York, NY) Project - Support",Auto Expense:Fuel,Fuel,1,29.41,29.41,0,29.41,True,Un Billed,Un-Submitted,,False,False,8/27/2021,,,Fuel,U.S. Dollar,0,False,0,0,0,1234-56 - Lastname - 1234,,,,"Bob & Bob, Inc.",1,,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021

> 8/27/2021,"Lastname, Firstname","2021-123 - Bob & Bob (Bob's - New York, NY) Project - Support",Airfare:Flight,Plane Ticket,1,658.4,658.4,0,658.4,True,Un Billed,Un-Submitted,,True,False,8/27/2021,,,Flight,U.S. Dollar,0,False,0,0,0,,,,,"Bob & Bob, Inc.",1,,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021

> 8/26/2021,"Lastname, Firstname","2021-123 - Bob & Bob (Bob's - New York, NY) Project - Support",Meals:Project Meals,Meals,1,32.28,32.28,0,32.28,True,Un Billed,Un-Submitted,,False,False,8/26/2021,,,Meals-Project,U.S. Dollar,0,False,0,0,0,1234-56 - Lastname - 1234,,,,"Bob & Bob, Inc.",1,,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021

> 8/26/2021,"Lastname, Firstname","2021-123 - Bob & Bob (Bob's - New York, NY) Project - Support",Meals:Project Meals,Meals,1,6.58,6.58,0,6.58,True,Un Billed,Un-Submitted,,False,False,8/26/2021,,,Meals-Project,U.S. Dollar,0,False,0,0,0,1234-56 - Lastname - 1234,,,,"Bob & Bob, Inc.",1,,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021,"Lastname, Firstname",8/27/2021

Comment: does this answer to your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18039057/python-pandas-error-tokenizing-data

Comment: can you show us line 3?  It could be there are some UTF quote characters that look like " but are actually different characters. Or, there are internal quotes not escaped, or it just isn't formatted properly

Comment: Give an exact example of the first 5 rows or so to reproduce the exact error.  Provide the full code needed to reproduce the error including imports.

Comment: Yes, since error is in row 3, showing us part of a row before that, which must be working, isn't helpful.

Comment: Sure, I've added those edits with a sanitized input file. The only other code imports Pandas and CSV, then sets the CSV filename for import.

Answer (score 1):

Try "csv.QUOTE_NONE"

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

myexpenses = pd.read_csv(myfilename, csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```