# extra commas when using read_csv causing too many "s in data frame

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas, delimiter

I'm trying to read in a large file (~8Gb) using pandas read_csv. In one of the columns in the data, there is sometimes a list which includes commas but it enclosed by curly brackets e.g.

"label1","label2","label3","label4","label5"

"{A1}","2","","False","{ "apple" : false, "pear" : false, "banana" : null}

Therefore, when these particular lines were read in I was getting the error "Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 37 fields in line 35, saw 42". I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24091356/pandas-read-csv-with-final-column-containing-commas) solution which said to add
sep=",(?![^{]*})" into the read_csv arguments which worked with splitting the data correctly. However, the data now includes the quotation marks around every entry (this didn't happen before I added the sep argument in).

The data looks something like this now:

"label1" "label2" "label3" "label4" "label5"

"{A1}" "2" "" "False" "{ "apple" : false, "pear" : false, "banana" : null}"

meaning I can't use, for example, .describe(), etc on the numerical data because they're still strings.

Does anyone know of a way of reading it in without the quotation marks but still splitting the data where it is?

Very new to Python so apologies if there is an obvious solution.

[serialdev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4504245/serialdev) found a solution to removing the "s but the data columns are objects and not what I would expect/want, e.g. the integer values aren't seen as integers.

The data needs to be split at "," explicitly (including the "s), is there a way of stating that in the read_csv arguments?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read in the data structure you specified, where the last element is an unknown length.

"{A1}","2","","False","{ "apple" : false, "pear" : false, "banana" : null}"

"{A1}","2","","False","{ "apple" : false, "pear" : false, "banana" : null, "orange": "true"}"

Change the separate to a regular expression using a negative forward lookahead assertion. This will enable you to separate on a ',' only when not immediately followed by a space.

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', sep='[,](?!\s)', engine='python', thousands='"')

print df

        0  1   2        3                                                  4
0  "{A1}"  2 NaN  "False"  "{ "apple" : false, "pear" : false, "banana" :...
1  "{A1}"  2 NaN  "False"  "{ "apple" : false, "pear" : false, "banana" :...
```

Specifying the thousands separator as the quote is a bit of a hackie way to parse fields contains a quoted integer into the correct datatype. You can achieve the same result using converters which can also remove the quotes from the strings should you need it to and cast "True" or "False" to a boolean.

Comment: Thank you for your answer - I've accepted as it does what I wanted in one line. :)

Answer (score 1):

Would this work since you have all the data that you need:

```
.map(lambda x: x.lstrip('\"').rstrip('\"'))
```

So simply clean up all the occurrences of `"` afterwards

EDIT with example:

```
mydata = [{'"first_name"' : '"bill', 'age': '"75"'},
          {'"first_name"' : '"bob', 'age': '"7"'},
          {'"first_name"' : '"ben', 'age': '"77"'}]
IN: df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
OUT:
  "first_name"   age
0        "bill  "75"
1         "bob   "7"
2         "ben  "77"

IN: df['"first_name"'] = df['"first_name"'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('\"').rstrip('\"'))
OUT:
0    bill
1     bob
2     ben
Name: "first_name", dtype: object
```

Use this sequence after selecting the column, it is not ideal but will get the job done:

```
.map(lambda x: x.lstrip('\"').rstrip('\"'))
```

You can change the Dtypes after using this pattern:

```
df['col'].apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x, errors='ignore'))
```

or simply:

```
df[['col2','col3']] = df[['col2','col3']].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

Comment: No, it didn't work for some reason..
I made a quick demo:
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['"first_name"', '"age"']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'"first_name"': '"Bill"', '"age"': '"7"'})
    writer.writerow({'"first_name"': '"Bob"', '"age"': '"8"'})
    writer.writerow({'"first_name"': '"Ben"', '"age"': '"9"'})

df = pd.read_csv('names.csv')
df.replace('"', '')

If you run in, the "s will still be there. Do you have any other ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the edit :)

I found df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.lstrip('\"').rstrip('\"')) applied it to the whole data frame at once so does remove the " problem. However, when you look at df['"age"'].dtype it says it's an object when it should be an integer. Think it's best to either split at  "," or look into changing the data source.

Comment: Yes this does only remove the "s, after that you should define the desired dtypes I have added a further edit for that. Consider accepting the answer if that solves all the issues

Comment: Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

If need remove `"` from column, use vectorized function [`str.strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html):

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = [{'"first_name"': '"Bill"', '"age"': '"7"'},
          {'"first_name"': '"Bob"', '"age"': '"8"'},
          {'"first_name"': '"Ben"', '"age"': '"9"'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
print (df)
  "age" "first_name"
0   "7"       "Bill"
1   "8"        "Bob"
2   "9"        "Ben"

df['"first_name"'] = df['"first_name"'].str.strip('"')
print (df)
  "age" "first_name"
0   "7"         Bill
1   "8"          Bob
2   "9"          Ben
```

If need apply function `str.strip()` to all columns, use:

```
df = pd.concat([df[col].str.strip('"') for col in df], axis=1)
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')
print (df)
  age first_name
0   7       Bill
1   8        Bob
2   9        Ben
```

**Timings**:

```
mydata = [{'"first_name"': '"Bill"', '"age"': '"7"'},
          {'"first_name"': '"Bob"', '"age"': '"8"'},
          {'"first_name"': '"Ben"', '"age"': '"9"'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
df = pd.concat([df]*3, axis=1)
df.columns = ['"first_name1"','"age1"','"first_name2"','"age2"','"first_name3"','"age3"']
#create sample [300000 rows x 6 columns]
df = pd.concat([df]*100000).reset_index(drop=True)
df1,df2 = df.copy(),df.copy()

def a(df):
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')
    df['age1'] = df['age1'].str.strip('"')
    df['first_name1'] = df['first_name1'].str.strip('"')
    df['age2'] = df['age2'].str.strip('"')
    df['first_name2'] = df['first_name2'].str.strip('"')
    df['age3'] = df['age3'].str.strip('"')
    df['first_name3'] = df['first_name3'].str.strip('"')
    return df

def b(df):
    #apply  str function to all columns in dataframe
    df = pd.concat([df[col].str.strip('"') for col in df], axis=1)
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')
    return df

def c(df):
    #apply  str function to all columns in dataframe
    df = df.applymap(lambda x: x.lstrip('\"').rstrip('\"')) 
    df.columns = df.columns.str.strip('"')
    return df

print (a(df))
print (b(df1))
print (c(df2))
```

```
In [135]: %timeit (a(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 635 ms per loop

In [136]: %timeit (b(df1))
1 loop, best of 3: 728 ms per loop

In [137]: %timeit (c(df2))
1 loop, best of 3: 1.21 s per loop
```

Comment: And if need cast to integer some column, use [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) -  `df['age1'] = df['age1'].str.strip('"').astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

It depend on your file. Did you check your data if there is comma or not, in cell ? If you have like this e.g Banana : Fruit, Tropical, Eatable, etc. in same cell, you're gonna get this kind of bug. One of basic solution is removing all commas in a file. Or, if you can read it, you can remove special characters :

```
 >>>df
                 Banana
 0  Hello, Salut, Salom
 1              Bonjour


 >>>df['Banana'] = df['Banana'].str.replace(',','')
 >>>df
               Banana
 0  Hello Salut Salom
 1            Bonjour
```

Comment: The problem is that every entry in the data frame is surrounded by quotation marks. In my question it shows an example:
{A1}" "2" "" "False" "{ "apple" : false, "pear" : false, "banana" : null}" would be a row of data where "2" is a string and not an integer. I would like the data as it is - the commas aren't an issue - just without quotation marks around everything.